# MC Connect: What if the Contact record is deleted?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We use the MC Connect to sync our SFDC Contacts in SFMC.

We cannot use the standard fields like "IsDeleted" for filtering because we have specific requirements which Contacts to sync. Thats why we created a custom boolean field.

Imagine 1) one Contact matches the filter criteria (MCSync__c = true) and is snyced by MC Connect and part of the Synchronized DE in SFMC.
Imagine 2) Contact is deleted physically in SFDC.

What does the MC Connect in that case? 
Will the Contact remain in the Synchronized DE?
Is the Contact deleted in the Synchronized DE?

(We do not have access to IsDeleted in our custom field MCSync__c)

Answer (score 1):

This contact will be removed from the Synchronized DE, but will still remain a billable contact unless you remove it from Marketing Cloud.

Depending on how you enegaged with this contact, it will be in:

- All Contacts (in Contact Builder)
- All Subscribers (in E-mail Studio)
- MobileConnect (in Mobile Connect)

You can then try to automate the deletion of such contacts or perform it periodically with a manual process.

Comment: are you sure? Do you see the difference between using the standard flag "IsDeleted" and a custom field "MCSync__c"?